# Swift Firebase Group Messenger Data - Profile Picture and Name

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a group messenger and am trying to keep users profile image and name up-to-date incase they decide to change their profile image or update their name. The problem is when I am populating the cells, the data is getting mismatched. So everything loads, the image and name, but it is the wrong people getting loaded.

**Calling and setting all users (customers,employees, and businesses)**

This is setting the users to a data structure

```
func getCustomerData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("user_profiles").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.customerData.append(CustomerData(snapshot: snapshot))
        print(snapshot)
        print("Printed Customer Data")
    })
}

func getEmployeeData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("employees").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.employeeData.append(EmployeeData(snapshot: snapshot))
        print(snapshot)
        print("Printed Employee Data")
    })
}

func getBusinessData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        self.businessData.append(BusinessData(snapshot: snapshot))
        print(snapshot)
        print("Printed Business Data")
    })
}
```

**Data Structure for customers, employees, and business. Same type of structure for all 3**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CustomerData: NSObject {

var customerName: String?
var customerPicture: String?
var customerUID: String?

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        customerName = dictionary["name"] as? String
        customerUID = dictionary["uid"] as? String
        customerPicture = dictionary["profPicString"] as? String
    }
}
}
```

**Cell Set Up**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

    cell.chatLogController = self

    let customer = customerData[indexPath.item]
    let employee = employeeData[indexPath.item]
    let business = businessData[indexPath.item]

    let message = messages[indexPath.row]

    cell.message = message
    cell.customer = customer
    cell.employee = employee
    cell.business = business

    setupChatMessageCell(cell,message,customer,employee,business)

    if let text = message.text {
        cell.textView.text = text
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimateSizeOfText(text).width + 32
        cell.textView.isHidden = false
    } else if message.imageUrl != nil {
        cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = 200
        cell.textView.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.playButton.isHidden = message.videoUrl == nil

    return cell
}


private func setupChatMessageCell(_ cell: ChatMessageCell, _ message: GroupMessage, _ customer: CustomerData, _ employee: EmployeeData, _ business: BusinessData) {

    if message.fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        //outgoing messages
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = ChatMessageCell.blueColor
        cell.textView.textColor = .white
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .gray
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLabel.text = customer.customerName?.description
        //cell.nameLabel.text = message.customerName
    } else if message.fromId == business.businessUID?.description {
        //incoming messagese
        let customerImage = business.businessPicture?.description
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(customerImage!)
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.nameLabel.text = business.businessName
    } else {
        let customerImage = employee.employeePicture?.description
        cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(customerImage!)
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240, green: 240, blue: 240)
        cell.textView.textColor = .black
        cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.nameRightAnchor?.isActive = false
        cell.nameLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.nameLabel.text = employee.employeeName
    }

    if let imageUrl = message.imageUrl {
        cell.messageImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(imageUrl)
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = false
        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = .clear
    } else {
        cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

**Firebase Group Messages Structure**

[image]

I need help on how I can match the message "fromId" to the right user. I have 3 different profiles, customers, employees, and businesses. As of now the wrong data is being set for the business and employee messages. The data for the customer is correct which is the first "if else" statement.

**How Data is loaded**

[image]

So as you can see he displayed name and profile picture is different from the name inside the message.

Comment: The Cell Setup section is a bit suspect; it seems you're attempting to load a customer, employee and business into the same cell? What will happen here *let message = messages[indexPath.row]* if there's 25 customers and 10 employees. All of the messages are stored in one array, *message*; does that correspond to the other arrays? Also when setting up the cell, why a .fromId would equal a .description in *message.fromId == business.businessUID?.description*. Can the code be shortened? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh - also in the *setupChatMessageCell* function, a customer, employee and business is passed in. The if statement handles when the message is from the current user (outbound) and also if it's from a business (I think) and then if it's from an employee or customer it falls into the last else statement where *let customerImage = employee.employeePicture?.description*. It's not clear how that's supposed to work.